# Receiving string instead of array

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

```
const req = require('request-promise');
const urlAllBase = 'https://cs.money/730/load_bots_inventory?v=1237';
function getBase() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(req.get(urlAllBase, (err, res, body) => body));
    });
}

async function base() {
    try {
        const done = await getBase();
        console.log(done[1]);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }


}
base();
```

Why I receiving a string if it is looks like array with objects?

```
[{ "id":[""], "p":16634.69, {"id":[""], "p":3468.74,"vi":[],"ai":[""],"bi":[""],"bl":[],"f":["0.11143143"],"ss":["s"],"ui":["705703"],"cp":14999,"pd":332.4,"d":[""]}]
```

Comment: It is JSON.....

Comment: https://dev.to/isalevine/three-ways-to-retrieve-json-from-the-web-using-node-js-3c88

Comment: it is NOT `json` : look [here](https://jsonlint.com)